# Fedora wireless: mac change every reboot (with NetworkManager disabled)

Tags: fedora, wifi

I have configured Fedora for starting wireless network

First editing /etc/wpa/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="mysid"
    psk="mypassword"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Then I create this file

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-mysid
```

And I edit it..

```
ESSID="mysid"
MODE=Managed
KEY_MGMT=WPA-PSK
TYPE=Wireless
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.0.6
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=mysid
UUID=abcde-...
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=**:**:**:**:**:**
MACADDR=**:**:**:**:**:**
SECURITYMODE=open
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Work for first time...
But on every reboot I see mac of wifi change. How to put a fixed macaddr for the device?
My router accept only known MAC; if the MAC changes, it drops connection.
NetworkManager were disabled

Comment: Are you using Networkmanager?

Comment: No,is disabled atm

Comment: Writing a  script which contain the command to change the mac address + `wp_supplicant` command to connect, then create a cron job to make the script work on boot time.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to disable NetworkManager?

Comment: @mattdm Right, enabling the networkmanager can be used to solve the problem. [How to stop MAC address from changing after disconnecting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395059/how-to-stop-mac-address-from-changing-after-disconnecting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround

Enable NetworkManager

add

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

to NetworkManager.conf

And run this script before boot

```
#!/bin/sh    
HWADDR=**:**:**:**:**
ifconfig wlp6s0 down 
macchanger --mac="$HWADDR" wlp6s0
ifup mynet
```

OR A better and easy solution using NetworkManager

add

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

to NetworkManager.conf

Then run..

```
nmcli device wifi connect mysidname password "pass!"
```

Easy!